# Using SqlGeography in code-first EF6 not generating column

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'm using VS2013, .Net 4.5, EF6, MVC5 and the MSSQL server is 11.00.2100

When I create a property in my model called:

```
public SqlGeography Position { get; set; }
```

and then use **update-database** no changes are made to the database table of that model.

I'm using SqlGeography from this reference:

**Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography**

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `DbGeography` type from EF which will be then translated to `SqlGeography` by the Sql Server provider.

Comment: So later if I want to do anything with the SqlGeography I can cast SqlGeography to the DbGeography object or is it that DbGeography is the LINQ equivalent of SqlGeography in the MVC5 models?

Comment: No. You won't even have SqlGeography type. DbGeopgraphy is an EF abstraction of spatial type while SqlGeography is actual implementation. Since EF can work with different databases it does not expose native database types. AFAIR if you want to work with spatial types you just need to use methods exposed by DbGeopgraphy/DbGeometry types.